# Problem with deploying using ARM Template for API Management Service and it's APIs

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy an Azure API Management Service with it's associated APIs by using ARM Templates. The goal here is to be able to easily provision new instances of API Management Service with it's associated APIs and all its settings but be able to change the backend url by using parameters. For this, I exported a template using the Azure portal and changed it to according to my needs to be able to pass in the backend url as a parameter. However, I'm running into a few issues:

Template deployment returned the following errors:

UPDATE: THE COMMENT HELPED ME FIX THIS. Please ignore this error now.

```
16:12:24 - 4:11:50 PM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions 'testAPITalhaNEW1/master' failed with message '{
16:12:24 -   "error": {
16:12:24 -     "code": "ValidationError",
16:12:24 -     "message": "One or more fields contain incorrect values:",
16:12:24 -     "details": [
16:12:24 -       {
16:12:24 -         "code": "ValidationError",
16:12:24 -         "target": "scope",
16:12:24 -         "message": "Subscription scope should be one of '/apis', '/apis/{apiId}', '/products/{productId}'"
16:12:24 -       }
16:12:24 -     ]
16:12:24 -   }
16:12:24 - }'
16:12:24 - 4:11:50 PM - Subscription scope should be one of '/apis', '/apis/{apiId}', '/products/{productId}'
16:12:24 - 4:12:01 PM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups/users 'testAPITalhaNEW1/administrators/1' failed with message '{
16:12:24 -   "error": {
16:12:24 -     "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
16:12:24 -     "message": "System group membership cannot be changed",
16:12:24 -     "details": null
16:12:24 -   }
16:12:24 - }'
16:12:24 - 4:12:01 PM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups/users 'testAPITalhaNEW1/developers/1' failed with message '{
16:12:24 -   "error": {
16:12:24 -     "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
16:12:24 -     "message": "System group membership cannot be changed",
16:12:24 -     "details": null
16:12:24 -   }
16:12:24 - }'
16:12:24 - 4:12:01 PM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users 'testAPITalhaNEW1/1' failed with message '{
16:12:24 -   "error": {
16:12:24 -     "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
16:12:24 -     "message": "Cannot modify property for user with built-In role",
16:12:24 -     "details": null
16:12:24 -   }
16:12:24 - }'
```

Originally the line was :

```
        "scope": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/master', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name')), '/')]",
```

which I changed to:

```
        "scope": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/apis', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name')), '/')]",
```

This didn't fix the issue either.

Error: "Subscription scope should be one of '/apis', '/apis/{apiId}', '/products/{productId}'"

```
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions",
      "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'), '/master')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'))]"
      ],
      //Changed from master to apis
      "properties": {
        "scope": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/apis', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name')), '/')]",
        "displayName": "Built-in all-access subscription",
        "state": "active",
        "primaryKey": "a4a0311b7af34f8fad57cdf8e06723fb",
        "secondaryKey": "3bfb52667eb443a0a430e298b402da03",
        "allowTracing": true
      }
    }
```

Error: MethodNotAllowed : "Cannot modify property for user with built-In role"

```
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users",
      "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'), '/1')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "firstName": "Administrator",
        "email": "xxx@hotmail.com",
        "state": "active",
        "identities": [
          {
            "provider": "Azure",
            "id": "xxx@hotmail.com"
          }
        ],
        "lastName": "[parameters('users_1_lastName')]"
      }
    }
```

The email that I have taken out is the primary email that the Azure account is registered on...

If I remove this piece of code, I get more failures about the resource not being found so I believe there is a dependency in my ARM Template on this particular piece of code/resource.

The end goal here is to be able to easily go from development to testing to staging to production using the ARM template and having everything from the API Management Service and it's APIs intact and just be able to change the backend URL. I believe I'm almost there, just trying to debug this script and any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue but have resolved the problem.
Most likely, you have generated the ARM template based on the 'Export template' function?

This will generate two 'default' subscriptions and a default user, the administrator.
Remove all three and your template should run, without issues.
The 'Starter' and 'Unlimited' subscription for the administrator are always created without ARM template instructions.

So remove the Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users section with:

```
"[concat(parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'), '/1')]"
```

and the two subscription sections that contain:

```
"ownerId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'), '1')]",
"scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'), 'starter')]
```

and:

```
"ownerId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'), '1')]",
"scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name'), 'unlimited')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this resource which will be helpful: [azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit/tree/master/example/subscriptions)

Try

```
"scope": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('service_testAPITalha_name')), '/apis')]",
```

Comment: thank you! That fixed one of the errors, but now I'm getting this error:                                    17:42:12 - Template deployment returned the following errors:
17:42:12 - 5:41:50 PM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups/users 'testAPITalha-newest/administrators/1' failed with message '{
17:42:12 -   "error": {
17:42:12 -     "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
17:42:12 -     "message": "System group membership cannot be changed",
17:42:12 -     "details": null
17:42:12 -   }
17:42:12 - }'

Comment: please look at the updated post to see the error that remains to be fixed. Thanks for your help

Comment: You might need to remove the `Identities` param and add an `"confirmation": "invite"` param. See here https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit/blob/master/example/users.template.json and here https://blog.eldert.net/api-management-ci-cd-using-arm-templates-products-users-and-groups/

Comment: seems like that didn't work:                                                                                             
09:53:36 - 9:53:13 AM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions 'testAPITalha-newest/master' failed with message '{
09:53:36 -   "error": {
09:53:36 -     "code": "ValidationError",
09:53:36 -     "message": "One or more fields contain incorrect values:",
09:53:36 -     "details": [
09:53:36 -       {
09:53:36 -         "code": "ValidationError",
09:53:36 -         "target": "Scope",
09:53:36 -         "message": "Can't modify global subscription"

Comment: 09:53:36 - 9:53:18 AM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups/users 'testAPITalha-newest/developers/1' failed with message '{
09:53:36 -   "error": {
09:53:36 -     "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
09:53:36 -     "message": "System group membership cannot be changed",
09:53:36 -     "details": null
09:53:36 -   }
09:53:36 - }'

Comment: So I commented out a lot of lines that contained Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups/users or the errors pointed out and it seemed to work and achieve the purpose of being able to change the backendURL using a parameter. However, I'm unsure of why I can't change group memberships. What would be the use case of this? I'm unsure if I will need to configure these in the future while migrating from one environment to another.